# How do I get flutter run -d chrome to use https?

Tags: flutter

I've been using `flutter run -d chrome` to start a web version of my app. The app uses FirebaseAuth and when I try to login using Google it tells me it's not secure. I think because the `run` command is setting up the server for http requests instead of https. If I try just changing the url to https I get an error.

I've looked all over and cannot find any options to tell flutter to use https. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Can you try HTTPS Everywhere extension in Chrome and see if it let work ?

Comment: I used the library dio and with that had no issues at all making requests from http to https

Comment: Any luck , while running flutter web with https, I am also getting same. I have created self signed certificate also. Its is always opening with http://localhost:8444. Please suggest if you have any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build it and serve it via a webserver. You need a certificate that chrome tells you that the website is secured.