# How to run flutter web application locally with https?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-test

I built **flutter** application for web. And able to launch the app using the below command.

```
flutter run -d chrome
```

But the above command launches my web app in chrome with `http://localhost:59111`.
I need to test web application in https:// not with http://

Can anyone suggest me to launch web app with https:// localhost.

Comment: `localhost` always run on `http://localhost` but if you want to make secure refer here.https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get flutter run -d chrome to use https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61320824/how-do-i-get-flutter-run-d-chrome-to-use-https)

Comment: @cubuspl42 I don't know how to do it via a webserver. I guess that is my question. Anyways it says build it, so maybe it is referring to the production build. In any case , I don't know which steps to follow _after_ creating the certificate.

Comment: Any luck , while running flutter web with https, I am also getting same. I have created self signed certificate also. Its is always opening with localhost:8444. Please suggest if you have any solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert) to mock a trusted certificate while testing locally using localhost. `mkcert` automatically creates and installs a local Certificate Authority (CA), and generates locally-trusted certificates.

Follow [this guide](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert#installation) to install mkcert. On macOS, this can be installed using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

```
brew install mkcert
```

Run `mkcert -install` on the terminal to create a new local certificate authority using mkcert. Then run `mkcert localhost` - this makes all **localhost** address trusted. Other samples are demonstrated in [here](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert#mkcert).

Comment: Can you explain please how to do it? I already created the certificate for localhost, now what do I do? I tried manually inputting `https://localhost:8080` but this doesn't work

Comment: Once you've set `mkcert localhost`, this generates a locally-trusted certificate and all 'localhost' address will be trusted in your local machine.

Comment: Hi 
I have install as brew install mkcert then after I did run mkcert -install and then mkcert localhost
After all these I did run my flutter web but still no luck please.