# Flutter http insecure request in web chrome

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

In this question: [Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64197752/bad-state-insecure-http-is-not-allowed-by-platform?newreg=673318c29c8a4529a8ff0f1a20b29866) we can find solution for ios and Android, but how we fix it in Chrome web platform? I try do it in `Flutter 2.0.3`

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61320824/how-do-i-get-flutter-run-d-chrome-to-use-https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it. If You need http insecure request, You must allow to do it. There is information how to allow it: https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/network-policy-ios-android

Answer (score 0):

**You can try to make secure call using https:**

```cs
Response response = await get('https://you_api_url');
```

Comment: It is my own test server, i can't use httpS now. I search for the same way to solve it like here ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64197752/bad-state-insecure-http-is-not-allowed-by-platform?newreg=673318c29c8a4529a8ff0f1a20b29866 ), but for web project, not ios/android